# Как отслеживать запуски GC и учитывать их при логировании из разных потоков?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, логирование

Из разных потоков вызывается метод и надо логировать его работу. Т.к. GC при сборке мусора в WinForms и WPF приложениях может приостановить работу потоков приложения, то это надо учитываться при логировании.
Как можно отслеживать запуски GC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того чтобы отслеживать GC надо вызвать метод [RegisterForFullGCNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.gc.registerforfullgcnotification(v=vs.110).aspx), а также [WaitForFullGCApproach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.gc.waitforfullgcapproach(v=vs.110).aspx) и [WaitForFullGCComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.gc.waitforfullgccomplete(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class LogLine {
    public int Number; 
    public int ThreadId; 
    public long Ticks; 
    public object Value;
    public long GCMemory; 
    public int[] GCCollections;
    public LogLine(int num, object value, long ticks) {
        this.Number = num; 
        this.Value = value; 
        this.Ticks = ticks;
        this.ThreadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
        this.GCMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
        int[] arr = new int[GC.MaxGeneration + 1];
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) arr[i] = GC.CollectionCount(i);
        this.GCCollections = arr;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Log : IDisposable {
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    BlockingCollection<LogLine> lines = new BlockingCollection<LogLine>();
    void Add(LogLine line) {
        if (!lines.IsAddingCompleted) lines.Add(line);
    }
    public Log() {
        GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification(1, 1);
        new Thread(() => {
            while (!lines.IsAddingCompleted) {
                Add(new LogLine(-1, GC.WaitForFullGCApproach(), sw.ElapsedTicks));
                Add(new LogLine(-2, GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(), sw.ElapsedTicks));
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    public void WriteLine(object value = null, [CallerLineNumber] int cnumber = 0) {
        Add(new LogLine(cnumber, value, sw.ElapsedTicks));
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose() {
        GC.CancelFullGCNotification();
        Add(new LogLine(-3, "Disposed", sw.ElapsedTicks));
        lines.CompleteAdding();
    }
    public IEnumerable<string> ToCsv() {
        var s = ",\t ";
        yield return String.Concat(
            "Number", s, "Ticks", s, "ThreadId", s, "GCMemory", s, 
            "GCCollections", s, "Value");
        foreach (var l in lines)
            yield return String.Concat(
                l.Number, s, l.Ticks, s, l.ThreadId, s, l.GCMemory, s,
                String.Join(";", l.GCCollections), s, l.Value);
    }
}
```

---

Для теста в двух потоках создаем и заполняем список массивов по 100 тыс. int

```
var log = new Log();
using (log) {
    Parallel.For(0, 2, i => {
        var lst = new List<int[]>();
        log.WriteLine("new List");
        try { 
            while (true) lst.Add(new int[100000]); 
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException) {
            log.WriteLine("OutOfMemory; lst.Count=" + lst.Count);
        }
    });
}
```

Выводим собранные данные

```
foreach (var line in log.ToCsv()) 
   Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Результат (получен в C# Interactive, Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204)

```
Number, Ticks,   ThreadId, GCMemory,    GCCollections, Value
55,     4030,    6,        6905852,     1;0;0,         new List
55,     4426,    9,        6905852,     1;0;0,         new List
-1,     274370,  11,       1481676908,  6;5;5,         Succeeded
-2,     274430,  11,       1482877004,  6;5;5,         Succeeded
-1,     277392,  11,       1528080620,  6;5;5,         Succeeded
58,     355462,  6,        1528087152,  8;7;7,         OutOfMemory; lst.Count=1888
58,     355462,  9,        1528087152,  8;7;7,         OutOfMemory; lst.Count=1920
-2,     317257,  11,       1528087152,  8;7;7,         Succeeded
-3,     356158,  6,        1528095344,  8;7;7,         Disposed
```